# How to move EVERYTHING to external drive

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, storage, reset

I plan to format my laptop although I've files on there that I don't want to lose.
My question: How can I move / copy **ALL** files from my laptop to an external drive?
The OS is Windows 10.

Comment: The usual copy/paste actions don't work for you? Please explain why not...

Comment: This is something only you can know. Copy your complete User Profile to another drive. Then, copy documents, email and such from your User Profile to another folder on the other drive. This gives you two passes of documents and ensures no permission issues.  Then copy any other folders you know contain documents not in your profile.

Comment: ALL files is pointless.  Do you really want the swap file (aka paging file), temp directories, driver store, installations from program files that won't work if copied?  This list goes on and on.  If you don't plan on restoring this drive to be boot worthy,  copying everything is not advantageous.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure of getting *everything*, take a backup image of your drive.

You could for example use
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).

The resulting backup is typically on one file that contains only
the used sectors from the disk and is in addition compressed,
so that the backup is much smaller than the original disk.

Whenever you need to access your backup, you may open the file
from AOMEI as a virtual disk and access all the files as needed.

Better verify that everything works as described, before trusting that
backup.

Comment: The "Backup and Restore" tool left over from Windows 7 (and preinstalled on Windows 10) will do this.  It even uses the VHD format (which is universal and mountable).  Is there something better about the AOMEI tool?  (I am betting there is and I just don't know it)  ;-)

Comment: The Windows 7 Backup and Restore tool is deprecated and has many gotchas. I do not recommend this tool.